# Stop $interval on tab change in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two tabs one with home and another with menu.In menu tab I have two li's. Based upon selected li value need to display values in table.

Up to this everything went on well but my aim is to recall function $scope.clicked using $interval at every 3000 sec and to stop the $interval when I clicked on home tab and also on selected of menu tab (i.e i want to execute $interval only on selection of li in menu tab).

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NkasgPkl61nsaovyYZrT?p=preview)

```js
// Code goes here

var c = angular.module('myApp',[])
c.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$interval,$rootScope){
 
  $scope.home = function(){
    $rootScope.selected = "";
    console.log("Home Selected");
  };
  
  $scope.menu = function(){
    $rootScope.selected = "";
    console.log("Menu Selected")
    
  } 
  
  $scope.clicked = function(selected){
    console.log(selected)
    $rootScope.selected = selected;
    $scope.showTable = true;
    $scope.menuItems=[{"id":1,"name": 'Item1',"price":25},
    {"id":1,"name": 'Item2',"price":25},
    {"id":1,"name": 'Item3',"price":25},
    {"id":1,"name": 'Item4',"price":25},
    {"id":1,"name": 'Item5',"price":25},
    {"id":1,"name": 'Item6',"price":25},
    {"id":1,"name": 'Item7',"price":25}]
  }
  
     $interval(function() {
        $scope.clicked($rootScope.selected);
    }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.0/angular.min.js" data-require="angular.js@1.7.0" data-semver="1.7.0"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" ng-click=home()>Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" ng-click=menu()>Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3> {{data}}
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <li ng-click=clicked(1)>1</li>
      <li ng-click=clicked(2)>2</li>
      <li ng-click=clicked(3)>3</li>
        {{showTable}}
      <h3>Menu</h3>
       <table class="table" ng-if="showTable">
      <tr>
        <td>Menu Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.price}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    </div>
   </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/xWsHiA2e8KdKrEETOC4b?p=preview)

You can cancel the `$interval` using `$interval.cancel(timer)`;

```
c.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$interval){
  var timer;
  $scope.home = function(){
    console.log("Home Selected");
    $interval.cancel(timer);
  };

  $scope.menu = function(){
    console.log("Menu Selected")
    $interval.cancel(timer);
  } 

  $scope.clicked = function(selected){
    console.log(selected)
    timer = $interval(function(){
      console.log('hi')
    },300);
    $scope.menuItems=[{"id":1,"name": 'Item1',"price":25},
    {"id":1,"name": 'Item2',"price":25},
    {"id":1,"name": 'Item3',"price":25},
    {"id":1,"name": 'Item4',"price":25},
    {"id":1,"name": 'Item5',"price":25},
    {"id":1,"name": 'Item6',"price":25},
    {"id":1,"name": 'Item7',"price":25}]
  }


})
```